# Increment in nested if statement in python

Tags: python, if-statement, nested, increment

I have this function with nested if statements, where after the second if there is an increment of a variables. The problem is they are incremented only once, although the print method is executed as many times as there are instances of the number in question (zero or seven). If I move the increment line up and place it below the first if statement, the increment variable is updated, and it works. I tried the same code, a version of it in JavaScript and I haven't had this issue. I'd appreciate if someone could explain why is it happening, what is the Python logic behind it.

```
def spy_game(integers):
    zeros_index = 0
    seven_index = 0
    zeros_count = 0
    seven_count = 0
    for number in integers:
        if number == 0:
            if zeros_index < integers.index(number):
                zeros_index = integers.index(number)
                print(zeros_index)
                zeros_count = zeros_count + 1
                print(zeros_count)
        elif number == 7:
            if seven_index < integers.index(number):
                seven_index = integers.index(number)
                seven_count += 1
                print(seven_count)
    if zeros_count > 1 and seven_count > 0:
        return zeros_index < seven_index
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Can you add an example of how you call this function?

Comment: Assuming the built-in sequence meaning of `index`, it’s impossible for this code to increment `zeros_count` or `seven_count` more than once each.

Comment: Yes!!! You are correct, that's the problem! Thanks!